# Square root symbol label in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to get the square root sign inside a legend?
I tried \surd, but did not consider all my expression below this symbol.
\sqrt and \square do not work at all.

```
m=[2 4.8 7 9.1 11.5 15 20 29 59 90 130 190 250];
size(Te);
s=0:0.02:0.246;
size(s);
E0=0.1;
t0=0.05;
f=0.01;
I0=2e9;
I1=1e14.*[m./(3680.*(1.08)^(1./3))].^(1.5);
hold on
Ifitting=I0./(sqrt(2.*pi).*f).*exp(-[s-t0].^2./(2.*f.^2));
[ay,h1,h2]=plotyy(s.*1e6,I1,s.*1e6,Ifitting,'loglog','plot')
axes(ay(1)); ylabel(' Intensity');
axes(ay(2)); ylabel('Intensity [fitting]');
set(ay(1),'Ylim',[0 2e12])
set(ay(2),'Ylim',[0 2e12])
xlabel('time [\mu m]','FontSize',16,'FontName','Times-Roman');
set([h1],'marker','o')
set([h2],'marker','o')
b=legend([h1 h2], ['I=10^{14}'],['I_{fitting}=I_0$$\sqrt{(2)\sigma}$$e^{\sigma}']);  
set(b,'Interpreter','latex','fontsize',24)
```

Comment: Can you make do with something like `legend('x^{1/2}')`?

Comment: No, I need to make sqrt, I prefer that one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this:

```
plot(sqrt(1:10)); 
h = legend(['$$\sqrt{blah}$$'])
set(h,'Interpreter','latex','fontsize',24)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Better than my solution. What puzzles me is that `h = legend(['$\sqrt{blah}$'],'Interpreter','latex')` doesn't work

Comment: thanks. Yep, it is weird.  it seems like you can only "update" the interpreter after the legend object is created...

Comment: I wanted to make b=legend([h1 h2], 'I=10^{14}','I_{fitting}=I_0/$$\sqrt{(2\pi)}$$'); 

set(b,'Interpreter','latex','fontsize',24); But it gives an error : Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string "I=10^{14}" 
Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string "I_{fitting}=I_0/$$\sqrt{(2\pi)}$$"

Comment: Also, I have to add that I can make your. your instruction in my matlab at that case works. but in my case as I mentioned in the previous comment does not work

Comment: Please edit your question, and add a minimal code that should work but fails. I dont understand what's the meaning of the beginning of your legend `[h1 h2]` , are `[h1 h2]` numbers? text?

Comment: I put it in my question.

Comment: This also works for other text fields, like `title`, `xlabel`, `ylabel`.

Answer (score 4):

Create the legend with LaTeX-style text, and then set to `'latex'` the `'interpreter'` property of all children of the lenged that are of type `'text'`:

```
leg = legend('$\sqrt{x-1}$'); %// this will give a warning; ignore it
t = findobj('Parent',leg,'Type','text');
set(t,'Interpreter','latex')
```

It would be easier if `legend` accepted the `'interpreter'` property directly (`legend('$\sqrt{x-1}$','interpreter','latex')`), but it doesn't, at least in R2010b. ... However, it seems to work if *after* the legend object has been created; see [natan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863037/2586922).

Comment: @user3271929 It does for me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I gave my program in the question.