# Break long text in Matlab legend using plotyy

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The legend in my plot is too long, how can I break it into two lines? I'm plotting using `plotyy` and used this code:

```
leg = sprintf('I_{fitting}=I_0/(\surd{2\pi}\sigma)e^{-[t-t_0]^2/(2.\sigma^2)};\nso t_0=0.2\mus;\sigma=0.09\mus;I_0=4.8\cdot10^{10}W/cm^2') 
legend([h1 h2], 'I=10^{14}[T_e/(3680(1.054)^{1/3})]^{1.5}',leg);
```

Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you plot? Are you changing the Interpreter? Please provide an example where you actually call `plotyy` and determine `h1` and `h2`.

Comment: please look at on my previous question, I am trying to make this kind of broken legend there [link]{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862835/square-root-symbol-label-in-matlab/21863006?noredirect=1#comment33098760_21863006}

Comment: Please edit *this question* to be clear about the exact nature of the problem and provide a simple runnable example that demonstrates it. StackOverflow works best when you do a bit of work to help us help you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
>> leg = sprintf('This is a really long line\nso I broke it in two')
>> plot(1:10, 1:10)
>> legend(leg)
```

Which results in

[image]

This won't work if there are other characters in your legend that need to be escaped (e.g. if there is a lot of LaTeX). In that case you can insert a newline character manually -

```
>> newline = char(10);
>> leg = ['This is the first line', newline, 'and the second: A = 2\pi r^2'];
>> plot(1:10, 1:10);
>> legend(leg)
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: +1 I tried `\n` and ` \\ ` with LaTeX interpreter but to no avail. What is `\nso`?

Comment: @LuisMendo It is `\n` followed by the word so. Or were you kidding? (cause I know you have skills) =)

Comment: @RobertP. No, I was serious --blush-- :-) Now I see that it didn't work for me because I wasn't including `sprintf`

Comment: Yeah, it's a perpetual annoyance to me that the default in Matlab is not to escape characters in strings.

Comment: I am doing a plot in plotyy but it did not worked I used as follows: leg = sprintf('I_{fitting}=I_0/(\surd{2\pi}\sigma)e^{-[t-t_0]^2/(2.\sigma^2)};\nso t_0=0.2\mus;\sigma=0.09\mus;I_0=4.8\cdot10^{10}W/cm^2')
 
legend([h1 h2], 'I=10^{14}[T_e/(3680(1.054)^{1/3})]^{1.5}',leg); Can you tell me what is the problem???
%

Comment: @RobertP. Oh and thanks for trusting (too much) in my skills :-)

Comment: I down-voted because I don't think that this actually solves the OP's question. There's already an `'\n'` in the string being passed to `legend`, but I don't think both lines are printing. I think the issue is elsewhere. The question isn't very good though.

Comment: Though I see now you answered when the question was even less clear and didn't show code or mention `plotyy`. So I don't know when the OP added the `'\n'`. If you edit I'll be able to un-downvote.

Comment: @horchler Edited to answer the (new) question :)